# probability distribution of an array

Tags: distributions

Does anyone know how to get the probability distribution of an array. That is, I have an array of speeds in which there are n values ​​of v and I need to build a plot of dn / n

Comment: [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html)?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Is it possible to somehow plot a graph on a histogram

Comment: Can you give an example?  Maybe something like [`SmoothHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SmoothHistogram.html), or do you mean a graph is the sense of [`Graph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html)?  (The latter doesn't make sense to me but I'm trying to understand.)

Comment: Or if you want to overlay the `Histogram` with another graphic you can use [Show](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show).

Comment: Yeah thanks))))